# WordPress performance - loading backend scripts when logged in in frontend

Tags: wordpress

I use WordPress with the plugin "UserWP" to create a member area for logged in users. Everything is working and looking great but when i check the code i can see that on my pages (fronted) its loading tons of js and css that is used for the WordPress backend.

Example:
/wp-includes/js/media-views.min.js?ver=6.0.1
/wp-includes/js/dist/hooks.min.js?ver=c6d64f2cb8f5c6bb49caca37f8828ce3

And tons of other small scripts.

Is it possible to disable this for the pages i created and i use my frontend-template?

Answer (score 0):

CSS & JS files from `/wp-includes/` directory shouldn't be removed.

However, you can remove plugins and theme useless files using [wp_dequeue_style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dequeue_style/) or [wp_dequeue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dequeue_script/) functions.

These functions should be called inside your custom function and that custom plugin should be hooked with [wp_enqueue_scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_scripts/) action.

Answer (score 0):

WP-core is `wp-includes` & `wp-admin`. Those are needed for wordpress to function.

If you were trying to create your own styling and design, you instead want to create a theme and modify it. The theme exists in `wp-content`.